# How would this final variable be already assigned and not initialized?

Tags: java

I have a final variable, `save`, that is a serializble class for some information. What I've attempted to do is to set a final variable as that serializable class, however I get some conflicting warnings. I'm attempting to make it so that if the file isn't loadable / doesn't exist, it will simply create a new instance, otherwise it will use the old one.

My issue as it stands is commented in the code at the constructor opening, closing, and on reading the object from the ObjectInputStream

```
private final CannonSet save;


public CannonManager(ManCannon plugin) { // Warning that save is not initialized
    if (/* some conditional statement */) {
        //lot of code removed, unnecessary to problem
        //essentially, save was set conditionally here (loaded from file)
        this.save = new CannonSet();
    }
    if (this.save == null) {
        this.save = new CannonSet(); // Warning that save may have already been set
    }
}
```

Comment: You have *conditional* logic initializing it. So if the condition isn't met, it may not be initialized. The compiler is telling you that there's a route through the code that doesn't initialize it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But if that condition is met, then probably `save` as already been initialized?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That was my thought too, but I figured that if it isn't set by the end, it would be null, and if it is set, then I've ensured it isn't null through the null check?

Comment: @Rogue No, _you_ have to initialize it to some value, and you can only do so once (because it's `final`). This means that (a) it isn't initialized to `null`, and (b) if it's been initialized to `null`, you can't re-assign it to `new CannonSet()` (because it's `final`, which means it can't be re-assigned).

Comment: Aha, I see the flaw in my part there then.

Comment: @RohitJain: I'm talking about `if (!this.canFile.exists()) {` and `if (temp != null)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just need to declare your temp object at full method scope, test if it's null at the bottom where you are checking `this.save` instead, and then do the assignment.  Basically, just have one line ONLY where you assign the instance field.  Abbreviated from your code:

```
public CannonManager(ManCannon plugin) {
    CannonSet temp = null;
    try{
       // stuff happens
       temp = (CannonSet) in.readObject();
    }catch( ... ){
       // exception handling
    }
    if(temp == null){
       this.save = new CannonSet();
    }else{
       this.save = temp;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this to a final variable:

```
if (this.save == null) {
    this.save = new CannonSet(); // Warning that save may have already been set
}
```

If `save` was initialized - and only in this case comparison to `null` is possible, then you can't reassign it.

Conditional logic is possible with final variables and in many cases it looks similar to:

```
final CannonSet save;

if(condition1){
    save = new CannotSet(1);
} else
if(condition2){
    save = new CannotSet(2);
} else {
    save = new CannotSet(3); 
}
```

Comment: I managed to solve it differently, but upvote for a good answer anyhow!

Answer (score 1):

I found that using a temp variable throughout the constructor made this a lot simpler:

```
private final CannonSet save;

public CannonManager(ManCannon plugin) {
    CannonSet temp = null;
    /* code .... */
    if (temp == null) {
        this.save = new CannonSet();
    } else {
        this.save = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, this is definitely one of the good ways to solve the problem. If most/all of the code paths end up setting a value for `this.save`, then I like to not use the temp value -- that way, the compiler can double-check that I haven't missed a code path. But when most of them _don't_ set a non-`null` value (as in your case), I prefer the code pattern you've posted, since it keeps the code simpler.